# Github Copilot CLI npm version vs gh cli version - what to use in future

Tags: command-line, github, microsoft-copilot

There seem to be 2 variants of Github Copilot for CLI:

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@githubnext/github-copilot-cli
part of GH CLI: https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/github-copilot-in-the-cli/using-github-copilot-in-the-cli

My question is: are they both maintained and equivalent.
because i installed the NPM version and just updated it - still works fine. I don't have GH cli installed what is the main prerequisite for the 2nd option.

In other words should i switch or just stay with NPM version?

Comment: See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/86354

Comment: i do not have the problem, the "old" one was updated and works fine